# How to efficiently create const c string from string literal and appended int or long value

Tags: c++, string, int, append

In c++ how can I efficiently create a c string based on a literal and appended long/int value?  I logically want to do something like this:

```
const char *sql = "select * from MyTable where ID = " + longId;
```

Where longId is an int/long parameter.

Comment: Use a `std::string` to do the assembly work pretty much as you have shown, but throw a `std::to_string` in to convert `longId` into a `string`, then, get the cstring out of the assembled `string` with the `c_str` method. Turn on optimizations and the compiler should take care of the rest.

Comment: Depends. Is the string `sql` only used in the context where it is created, or will it be returned from a function and used by the caller of that function?    If the latter, you need to carefully manage lifetime of the string - both to ensure it exists when needed and to avoid a memory leak.  It is often preferable to assemble and work with the string as a `std::string`, since then it can (unlike a C string) be passed around safely by value, be passed by reference (while it exists) and won't introduce memory leaks.  A `const` c string can be readily obtained from a `std::string` too.

Comment: Only within the function -- this is short lived in a single function performing a DB retrieval from a SQLite database which only has a C interface.

Comment: Sql libraries generally provide a `bind` method to avoid [exploit](https://xkcd.com/327/) with manual string concatenation.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes thanks I know, I'm just focused on c and c++ string mechanics at this point, however, and trying to learn that -- no immediate clear answer for something this basic seems to suggest there is indeed a lot to learn!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This compiles an answer from user4581301 comment and I offer to delete if  user4581301 makes their own answer and asks me to.*
As suggested by user4581301, you can do:

```
std::string s = "select * from MyTable where ID = " + std::to_string(longId);
```

You can get a C string equivalent using `s.c_str()`, e.g.:

```
std::cout << s.c_str() << std::endl;
```

Comment: Open game. I didn't formally answer because the question is a bit open ended. This might not be the most efficient solution in terms of performance, but it is the most efficient to write and the performance difference between it and a faster solution will almost certainly be lost in the cost of the SQL query that's probably going to follow.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I'm suffering from a case of not knowing how to frame the question precisely since I just don't know enough of anything :-).  I'm trying to write a standalone C++ function that in turn calls a C lib to do a database lookup.  I want to provide a char* to the C lib that is my SQL statement (including numeric parm).  I'm not at all interested in nanosecond timing and compiler optimization competitions, just what makes sense based on trying to provide a char* to downstream C lib for a one-time function call.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer from H.S. is perfect, given the question asked.  Just a quick FYI, since I'm using Qt (which I didn't mention in the OP), I ended up using this code:

```
QString sql = QStringLiteral("SELECT v.drive_path_if_builtin, "
                                    "m.full_filepath "
                             "FROM media_table m "
                             "INNER JOIN volume_table v "
                                     "ON (v.id = m.volume_id) "
                             "WHERE m.id = %1;").arg(id);
```

... and then in the appropriate place, where I need a c-string, I used `qPrintable(sql)`.